# Glue wooden stairs

Tags: wood, adhesive, treehouse

We have a spiral staircase made of wood. What means can be used to solve the problem that the wood is solid again? I thought a wood glue like [this](https://www.amazon.de/UHU-48580-Holzleim-Express-Flasche/dp/B00473SOJU/ref=asc_df_B00473SOJU/?tag=googshopde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=229828318030&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=7345174475493093155&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9061136&hvtargid=pla-422882222065&th=1https://) one should do his job. [image]

Comment: Was no wood glue used on the mating surfaces? From the picture it looks like construction adhesive was used along the seam like a caulk; if so then of course it failed!

Comment: For any glue to bind, the surfaces must be clean of dirt, old glue, paint/oils, and must fit tight.  Most glues also need a time to set, so both pieces must be kept tightly together for that time, usually by clamps(or nails/screws, rope/tape).

Comment: There is no glue that can restore the broken-off wood that was designed to carry loads in cantilever action. What you need is a "carpenter" to repair the damaged stair.

Comment: @crip659 , that is good for an answer, the old glue needs to be removed before regluing.  If it were me, I would countersink screw holes and run 2 screws with the radius to draw it in first, after it is all cleaned to make sure it draws tight. Then remove the screws, add glue and refasten. Using aliphatic resin based glue, since it is strong and water cleanup.  It looks like it is a handrail to center post connection, according to the dimensions of the rest of the rail, so It should not be cantilevered at all.